# Timestamp is giving wrong time in smart contract

Tags: solidity, dapps

Today is June 17. but when I execute my function and store the following arguments.

**WriterModel(owner,postID, _postContent, now);**

"now", It returns the July 20 timestamp.

It perfectly working fine in remix IDE which returns the today timestamp but in my local (Angular+Truffle + smart contract ) it returns July 20.

Can you please give me where I were Wrong.?

Comment: Are you using Ganache, Rinkeby...?

Comment: I am using Ganache

Comment: @Suria Check the computer clock in your pc is synchronized. Remember the timestamp returned is the unix time so it is in UTC.

Comment: @Ismael , I have checked again there is no difference in my pc date and if it is UTC then the difference is just 5.30 hrs right ?

Comment: @phant0m can your please tell the other possibilities of storing time with that record ?

Comment: @Suria Does it happen if you restart ganache? Did you try with another blockchain? ie ropsten, rinkeby. Can you show us the raw values returned by the contract? Also having your contract code and javascript will help reproducing the bug.

Comment: @Ismael thank you. I will check and come back with the proper outputs...

Comment: I am also facing the same issue now. Have you found a fix to this? Or is this a characteristic of the Ganache blockchain that cannot be changed? I am using `block.timestamp` instead of  `now` which is deprecated.